# Countdown value update every second

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a countdown clock and it counts down every secound, but when the user enters a new value of second it it doesn't start over but continues from the previous value... how can I change this?

```
function clock() {
    var $s = $(".second"),
    s = setInterval(1000);
    setTimeout("clock()", 1000);
    $s.val(s).trigger("change");

}
clock();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z4LSN/3/

Comment: where does the user enter the value, post some html too.

Comment: You are not using the value they entered... You seem to be taking the `setInterval` result and stuffing it in the input???

Comment: I'm useing the plugin jquery knob http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/, the user enters a value by turning the chart

Comment: We need the rest of the problem (HTML and any other code). Put it all in a JSFiddle.

Comment: What do you want $s.val(s).trigger("change"); to do ? it wont updates by triggering change, you may use a $s.on("change") to update the clock

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z4LSN/1/

Comment: the fiddle don't seem to work

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z4LSN/3/

Comment: now it works!! please help, the thing i want is when the user drags up the chart (enter the input) that the counter start from there!

Comment: You need a complete rewrite to get user-sensible behavior. You have to stop the counter when the input gets focus, or when the user starts dragging the knob. Then restart the timer on blur (or after long delay since last key press), or when the knob stops being dragged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".second").knob()
    setUpClock();
        // destroy the prev clock during user input
    $(".second").keydown(function(){
          tearDownClock();
    });

        //restart the clock when the user navigates away from the input
    $(".second").blur(function(){
          if(!interval){
              setUpClock();
           }                    
    });
});
function clock(){
     var secHtml = $(".second");
     var sec = secHtml.val();
     if(sec-1>=0){
         secHtml.val(sec-1);
         secHtml.change();
     }
     else{
         tearDownClock();
     }

}
function setUpClock(){
    interval = setInterval(clock,1000);
}
function tearDownClock(){
    window.clearInterval(interval);
    interval=null;
}
```

**Here is the NEW UNBROKEN** [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PaU35/)

Comment: I actually downloaded the knob library and tried it. It worked for me.

Comment: can you set up a fiddle or something so i can se the file?? please

Comment: I am trying to do that now... but I am having trouble linking the knob library.

Comment: yes, i had the same so i pasted everything in the js file,

Comment: or just send me the files josef.carlsson@me.com

Comment: Its there now... Fiddle

Comment: I see that the timer works but the chart isn't uppdated,

Comment: Oh I fixed that as well... you need to say secHtml.change()

Comment: I think the fiddle link is broken,